# primefaces inputTextarea hardcoded value attribute entry doesn't line break

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:inputTextarea value="My Name
My Address
My City, State zip"/>
```

This renders as My Name         My Address         My City, State zip 
in one line.

How do I get this to display on new lines?

Comment: What if you have it in a backingbean property/field?

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working the way I thought I would, doesn't make much sense to me still why I can't do that in the value attribute though but it seems to be working now @Kukeltje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Html Entities](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) worked for me. Good luck

```
  <p:inputTextarea id="comments" value="My Name &#10;
  My Address &#10;
  My City, State zip"/>
```

[image]